# Paypal Express Checkout: How do I create a recurring profile?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I am using PayPal express checkout.and my billing cycle run in 6 month.

Below Flow used.

1. SetExpressCheckout
2. GetExpressCheckoutDetails
3. DoExpressCheckoutPayment
4. CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

Above 3 flow working perfectly. But my question about last flow. 
I can CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile using hosted page or because in API pass card detail this detail mandatory. Without card detail I can create recurring profile? Or other way to create recurring profile without card detail?

Other question is CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile cycle run once in 6 month that option not available in PayPal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/ :

In order to use CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile you must first already have a billing agreement set up. The billing agreement contains the card information. Create the billing agreement with SetExpressCheckout with parameters/values such as these:

```
USER:krondoian_api1.gmail.com
PWD:B999999999999
SIGNATURE:A9999999999999999
METHOD:SetExpressCheckout
VERSION:86
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT:1.23
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE:USD
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION:AUTHORIZATION
cancelUrl:https://example.com/cancel
returnUrl:https://example.com/success
L_BILLINGTYPE0:MerchantInitiatedBilling
L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0:ClubUsage
cancelUrl:https://example.com/cancel
returnUrl:https://example.com/success
```

In response to your other question about having a recurring payment process every 6 months, it is possible to do that. In the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile call, set the following parameters and values:

```
BILLINGPERIOD:month
BILLINGFREQUENCY:6
```

Comment: Thank you. 6 month problem solve but my question is without card detail i can create recurring profile?